# Pagination in CodeIgniter, need to disable query strings so we can cache

Tags: codeigniter, caching, pagination

We have a CI installation that has the following setting in our config...

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

We need this in order for another area of our application to run correctly with a third party API. What's happening, however, is that pagination is defaulting to a query string method of doing pagination, which doesn't play well with caching.

Right now, they look like this...

```
http://localhost/something/?&page=6
```

It's not playing well with caching, mainly because every page URL is the same page to CI. My goal is to get switched over to the below example without messing with global settings for the rest of my application.

I've been trying for hours to find a way to disable the above setting only within this single part of the application, so that we can properly have separate URLs for the pagination, like this...

```
http://localhost/something/1
http://localhost/something/2
http://localhost/something/3
```

So far, I have been unable to overide that setting for this controller, and honestly, I'm not sure there's even a way to actually do it. Any help is appreciated. There's got to be some method of disabling a feature for a single controller somehow.

Comment: To get query strings to play nice with caching, see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194714/codeigniter-caching-issue-when-dealing-with-query-string-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use [routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)?

```
$route['something/page/(:num)'] = "something?&page=$1";
```

---

edit: to turn off pagination query strings with `$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;`

system/libraries/Pagination.php

~line 134

change

```
    if ($CI->config->item('enable_query_strings') === TRUE OR $this->page_query_string === TRUE)
    {
        if ($CI->input->get($this->query_string_segment) != 0)
        {
            $this->cur_page = $CI->input->get($this->query_string_segment);

            // Prep the current page - no funny business!
            $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ($CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment) != 0)
        {
            $this->cur_page = $CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);

            // Prep the current page - no funny business!
            $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
        }
    }
```

to

```
        if ($CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment) != 0)
        {
            $this->cur_page = $CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);

            // Prep the current page - no funny business!
            $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
        }
```

~line 196

```
    if ($CI->config->item('enable_query_strings') === TRUE OR $this->page_query_string === TRUE)
    {
        $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url).'&amp;'.$this->query_string_segment.'=';
    }
    else
    {
        $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url, '/') .'/';
    }
```

to

```
        $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url, '/') .'/';
```

that might do it. Or maybe better form would be to hook into the page...

Comment: Well that's the funny thing. I could use routing, if it let me assign a different link structure for the pagination links. But as far as I can tell from the documentation, it automatically uses either of the two link examples based on what the above $config[] is set as.

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood your question.. You can try to turn of the query string in system/libraries/Pagination.php, around line 135. Comment out the `if` looking for global query_string. Updated my answer with example.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution...

```
$this->config->set_item('enable_query_strings',FALSE);
```

Just put this before you call your pagination logic in the controller. Thanks go to Taftse in the #codeigniter IRC channel for this simple override.