# Codeigniter Page cache with GET parameter

Tags: codeigniter, caching

I am newbie to CI cache. I am facing some weird problem with codeigniter page caching. `$this->output->cache(300);`
I was expecting that cached version would not load if arguments in `GET[]` would change. But it is loading cache without considering any `GET[]` parameters.

I have one page where it says whether comment has been saved or not [via  get parameter], 
`/product/product-name/?saved=true` redirecting to same page where comment form is located. But it is not working. How can i invalidate old cache and create new one depending upon the get parameter? or i need to change the behavior of my comment system?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Should i simply use `database cache` instead of `Web page cache` in this case?

Comment: Its too late, But I faced same problem and provided solution below. :)

Answer (score 3):

You just have to enable the `cache_query_string` option in the `config/config.php` file.

```php
$config['cache_query_string'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Thanks. This should be the accepted answer because does not change any core file and dont need additional codes or functions. Worked like a charm =)

Answer (score 2):

Create a cache_override hook to check if there are any GET[] variables set and then skip the cache_override.

[EDIT #1]

Here is an example:

Create this file in your hooks directory:

```
<?php

class GetChecker {

    public function checkForGet()
    {
        global $OUT, $CFG, $URI;

        if (isset($_GET) AND ! empty($_GET))
        {
            return;
        }

        if ($OUT->_display_cache($CFG, $URI) == TRUE)
        {
            exit;
        }
    }

}
```

Then add this to the config/hooks.php:

```
$hook['cache_override'][] = array(
    'class' => 'GetChecker',
    'function' => 'checkForGet',
    'filename' => 'GetChecker.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

I haven't tested it, it might need a little tweaking to work...

Comment: not sure if i'm getting what you are saying. is it possible to delete particular `page cache` file or simply skip cache page and load default page.

Comment: i tried putting `$this->output->cache(300);` in if condition, when no `GET[]` parameter is passed. but it did not help. I need to delete/skip cache file if parameter is specified.

Comment: Once a page is cached you can't skip it unless the cache file is deleted or older then the 300 sec.

Comment: it would take some time to implement this, for now i am going with database level caching. need a quick fix. I will surely let you know when i try this code. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Hi Clifford, now i have worked a little with hooks, can override cache function before it loads cached copy. problem with the above code is that it creates new cache when `GET[]` is specified. And loads cached copy even if `GET[]` has no parameter.

What i want is, if `GET[]` is specified, no need to create cache. Just load page as if cache is disabled.

can i delete cached copy in anyway? There is something silly that i am missing here!

Answer (score 1):

I test on CI 3+ , file system/core/Output.php 559 line, change this

```
if ($CI->config->item('cache_query_string') && !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']))
    {
        $uri .= '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }
```

on this

```
if ($CI->config->item('cache_query_string') /* && ! empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) */ && !empty($_REQUEST))
    {
        // $uri .= '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        $uri .= '?'.http_build_query($_REQUEST);

    }
```

And add string to your application/config/config.php

```
$config['cache_query_string'] = true;
```

it will be work with GET, POST, COOKIE ....
If need only GET, just $config['cache_query_string'] = true; - enough

Answer (score 0):

I found no easier way using `Hooks` to prevent writing cache, as its calling `_write_cache()` inside the `_display()` method itself of `CI_Output` class.

For quick and easiest solution I added two conditions to display cache and write cache, if Query String parameter has variable defined( `offset` in my case, as I wanted for pagination)

**Edit: system/core/Output.php**

Add Condition to prevent *writing cache*, if specific `GET` parameter found:

```
function _write_cache($output)
{
    if (isset($_GET['offset']) AND ! empty($_GET['offset']))
    {
        log_message('debug', " Don't write cache please. As as its matching condition");
        return;
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Add Condition to prevent *displaying cache*, if specific `GET` parameter found:

```
function _display_cache(&$CFG, &$URI)
{
    if (isset($_GET['offset']) AND ! empty($_GET['offset']))
    {
        log_message('debug', " Don't display cache please. As as its matching condition");
        return FALSE;
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```